# Modify shell behavior doesn't affect other commands in CodeBuild

Tags: bash, glob, aws-codebuild

I find that some commands in my CodeBuild buildspec don't always work as expected. Particullary, using the `set -f` command to change the behavior of the shell.

The following code snippet doesn't work as expected.

```yaml
# buildspec.yml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - set -f
      - touch file.txt
      - foo="*"
      - echo Value is $foo
```

I'm expecting CodeBuild to output `Value is *`, but what I see is `Value is file.txt`. The `set -f` command to prevent globbing has no affect. The star is interpreted as a wildcard and expanded to list all the files in the working directory.

I understand that I can prevent this behavior by quoting the variable. But for a particular use case, I need the variable `$foo` to be token split.

I found that it does work if I put the commands in a single entry.

```yaml
commands:
  - |
      set -f
      echo $foo
```

Is there a reason why `set -f` is not affecting other commands in the buildspec? Why does it work when it's a single entry, but not when specified as separate entries?